# AJAX call not replacing HTML

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I've got a form that calculates shipping based on user's postcode input. I'm retrieving user's text input of the postcode, retrieving the cost of shipping of that particular postcode via PHP, then using an AJAX call to transfer that back to output in the HTML for a total. However, he AJAX call isn't replacing the HTML.

The (relevant) HTML:

```
  <input type="text" id="postcode" name="postcode">
  <div id="result"></div>
```

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('#postcode').change(function(){
    $.ajax({

        type: "GET",
        url: "shipping.php",
        data: 'shipping=' + $('#postcode').val(),
        success: function(msg){
            $('#result').html(msg);
        }

    }); // Ajax Call
});
}); //document.ready
```

The PHP:

```
<?php

   $postcode = (is_numeric($_GET['postcode']) ? (int)$_GET['postcode'] : 0);

   if ($postcode >= 2000 && $postcode <= 2234) {
     $shipping = 55.00;
   } elseif ($postcode >= 2250 && $postcode <= 2310) {
     $shipping = 105.00;
   }

    echo $shipping;
?>
```

- If I type msg in the console, it returns undefined. Shouldn't it have a value (the postcode input does fall within the correct conditions)..?

Comment: Where is your HTML element which has id "result"?

Comment: tried alert(msg) to make sure you have a msg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$postcode = (is_numeric($_GET['postcode']) ? (int)$_GET['postcode'] : 0);
```

Change that line to:

```
$postcode = (is_numeric($_GET['shipping']) ? (int)$_GET['shipping'] : 0);
```

Answer (score 4):

By using:

```
$postcode = (is_numeric($_POST['postcode']) ? (int)$_POST['postcode'] : 0);
```

And:

```
$.ajax{ type: "GET", ... }
```

You're sending the post-code over a querystring using **GET**, but your PHP code is attempting to read the value from the **POST** body.

Answer (score 2):

Your ajax is sending GET and your PHP is reading $_POST, try this:

```
<?php

   $postcode = (is_numeric($_GET['postcode']) ? (int)$_GET['postcode'] : 0);

   if ($postcode >= 2000 && $postcode <= 2234) {
     $shipping = 55.00;
   } elseif ($postcode >= 2250 && $postcode <= 2310) {
     $shipping = 105.00;
   }

    echo $shipping;
?>
```